# .NET Core App deployed on Azure refers to deleted classes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application with a database using EF Core 2.1. The application is deployed on Azure. On Azure I have a App Service for the application itself. Furthermore I have an Azure SQL server and a database in it which is used by the application.

For deployment I use VSTS where every commit to the master triggers a build pipeline in VSTS. The build pipeline consist of the following jobs:

[image: build pipeline]

(Note that the test job is disabled because I have another issue with it, but it is not part of my question)

So far everything worked with this set up and there were no any issue with it. But recently I am facing the following issue:
In the previous version of the app I had some view models, for example:

```
public class OrderCloserModel
{
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cím")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cserék száma")]
    public int NumberOfChanges { get; set; }
}
```

So nothing special. After I deleted them (because I did not need them anymore) and pushed everything to the master, the CI build is invoked, then the new version of the app is deployed. Then I checked the app and it crashed. Then of course I checked the logging whether I have some problem there. What I found is that the application requires the view models I deleted. Well at first it may sound trivial, I deleted some models used by the new version of the app. But the fact is that those view models are not used anywhere!!! I tried to search for them (VS <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> "Find and  replace") in the codebase but there are no usage any of them. Only the declared classes.

What I tried is to recreate those files in the master (with no usage), deployed the app again, then the application works again! At first what I could think of is that somehow the old application is deployed, not the new one. But it is not the case since the features of the newly deployed app reflect to the expected new behaviours.

So the workaround was to recreate the missing models in the codebase, I placed a //TODO comment for deleting them later on. Well to be honest it feels really nasty for me, but my app works and can be used in production.

The following picture also shows that are no any issue during the build:
[image: sucessfull job]

What I could also think of is that there is maybe an Azure dll cache which uses some old dll's but I could not find any relevant issue/question/articles about it.

What do you think where the reason of the issue lies? If any more information needed, I include them as soon as possible, thanks for all!

Additinal info:
The publish job looks like the following:
[image]

The settings for the publish artifact job:
[image]

And last but not least the succesfull release log:
[image]

Comment: What does your "Publish" step (where you publish the application to Azure) look like?

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the response! I updated the question. If any more info needed, feel free to ask ;)

Comment: @DanielMann I forgot to mention that if run the application locally (on master) with VS2017 using the azure production live database, I have no any problem with the app, runs as expected.

Comment: Are you using azure-pipeline.yaml file for this?  If so, please provide the contents.  If not, there is much more flexibility in configuring build and publish tasks using YAML configuration.  Here is something to get you started:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml